# GNUPLOT in Linux

Tags: excel, linux, gnuplot

Is we generate gnuplot in linux terminal of excel sheet?

I want to ask that we generate gnuplot in linux termianl of text editor file. Can we generate gnuplot in linux terminal of excel sheet?

Please Answer me that we can generate gnuplot of excel sheet in linux terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, the answer is: no you can't plot (directly) an `Excel` sheet (.xls file) with `Gnuplot`. You should save your sheet in a comma-separated format (.csv) and plot that. Or you can simply copy-paste your data from your Excel file into a text file.